Google Lighthouse accessibility checker possibly giving false errors
Google Lighthouse Accessibility checker seems to have issues with web applications that have a complex dom structure. I use Esri Experience Builder developer when developing web applications and as long as the app is very simple I get an acceptable score, but If I need to develop something a little more complex with nested panels and widgets, my score quickly dips. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of control over Esri's implementation of ADA attributes and trying to go into the backend and fix issues is difficult. Here are a couple of examples, where I believe I am getting false failures:

Here is the ACTUAL HTML that is failing:


<ul aria-orientation="horizontal" role="tablist" class="jimu-nav tab-nav app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-sbfyfm text-center nav-underline nav">
  <div class="nav-button-group scroll-list app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-3vgrh" data-version="1">
    <button class="jimu-btn previous direction-button app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-fx26zo icon-btn btn btn- tertiary btn-sm" aria-label="Previous" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="icon-btn-sizer"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 12" role="none" focusable="false" class="jimu-icon svg-component app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1j7348z" width="12" height="12" aria-hidden="true"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="currentColor" d="M2.479 5.47 8.019.162a.59.59 0 0 1 .813 0 .534.534 0 0 1 0 .779L3.552 6l5.28 5.06a.534.534 0 0 1 0 .779.59.59 0 0 1-.813 0l-5.54-5.31a.726.726 0 0 1 0-1.058"></path><path d="M0 0h12v12H0z"></path></g></svg></span>
    </button>
    <div class="root">
      <div class="list app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-0" role="tablist">
        <div class="scroll- item text-truncate tag-size text-truncate nav-item">
          <a id="dataSource_1-18f7d9efa7a-layer-2-1-0" aria-selected="true" title="Open Boat Ramps" role="tab" aria-controls="dataSource_1-18f7d9efa7a-layer-2-1-tab-pane-0" tabindex="0" class="jimu-btn jimu-link active app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1g4zu7w nav-link jimu-outline-inside btn btn-default"><span class="jimu-nav-link-wrapper"><span class="tab-title">Open Boat Ramps</span></span></a></div><div class="scroll-item text-truncate tag-size text-truncate nav-item">
          <a id="dataSource_1-18f7d9fc773-layer-3-2-0" aria-selected="false" title="Closed Boat Ramps" role="tab" aria-controls="dataSource_1-18f7d9fc773-layer-3-2-tab-pane-0" tabindex="-1" class="jimu-btn jimu-link  app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1g4zu7w nav-link jimu-outline-inside btn btn-default"><span class="jimu-nav-link-wrapper"><span class="tab-title">Closed Boat Ramps</span></span></a></div></div></div>



From my understanding, Lighthouse is complaining about the role="tablist" attribute in the ul tag and the nested div beneath the button not containing any child nodes with the role="tab" attribute. There are, however two "a" tags containing the "tab" role beneath the second "tablist" node that I don't believe Lighthouse is seeing. I tried removing each of the "tablist" attributes, but still get a failing score, apparently the "ul" tag must have "tablist" attribute so if I try to remove the second "tablist" from the nested div, I still get a failing score because Lighthouse apparently will stop looking for a "tab" attribute after too many nested nodes. Don't know at this point if this is even fixable.
Another issue is that I am getting a failure for a div that does not exist.

I can't find this node anywhere in the Dom tree. Here is the only element that this error could be referring to:


<button data-widgetid="widget_153" class="jimu-btn avatar-button app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1xfehrd icon-btn btn btn-primary active" aria-label="Map Layers" style="border-radius: var(--sys-shape-1);">
<span class="icon-btn-sizer"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="none" focusable="false" class="jimu-icon svg-component app-root-emotion-cache-ltr-1j7348z" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.2255 0.0541939C10.0847 -0.0180646 9.91531 -0.0180646 9.77451 0.0541939L0.250808 4.94182C-0.0949808 5.11928 -0.0798931 5.59747 0.276457 5.75475L9.80016 9.95803C9.92694 10.014 10.0731 10.014 10.1998 9.95803L19.7235 5.75475C20.0799 5.59747 20.095 5.11928 19.7492 4.94182L10.2255 0.0541939ZM10 9.04467L1.54156 5.31154L10 0.970621L18.4584 5.31154L10 9.04467Z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="M0.676142 10.0408C0.437433 9.93867 0.154448 10.0349 0.0440785 10.2558C-0.0662915 10.4766 0.037748 10.7384 0.276457 10.8406L10 15L19.7235 10.8406C19.9623 10.7384 20.0663 10.4766 19.9559 10.2558C19.8456 10.0349 19.5626 9.93867 19.3239 10.0408L10 14.0293L0.676142 10.0408Z" fill="currentColor"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.676142 15.0408C0.437433 14.9387 0.154448 15.0349 0.0440785 15.2558C-0.0662915 15.4766 0.037748 15.7384 0.276457 15.8406L10 20L19.7235 15.8406C19.9623 15.7384 20.0663 15.4766 19.9559 15.2558C19.8456 15.0349 19.5626 14.9387 19.3239 15.0408L10 19.0293L0.676142 15.0408ZM10 19.0293L10.1998 19.1147H9.80016L10 19.0293Z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
</span>
</button>



This must be the failing element that Lighthouse is referring to because of the background color (used for all of the map tool buttons) and the node clearly has a "button" tag, NOT and "div" tag, which is labeled correctly. Not sure what Lighthouse is seeing here. Appreciate any insights on Lighthouse in general as an accessibility checker or on the above errors. What I am concerned about is spending a lot of time trying to fix issues if I am not getting the correct results from the analysis.

The analysis and message are correct. Every tablist must have one or more tab children.
A tablist > tablist > tab pattern is invalid in the same way that a ul > ul > li pattern is invalid.

I fixed the first issue by changing the "ul" tag to a "div" and removing the "taglist" and "aria-orientation" attributes. I think Esri uses a lot of generic code that doesn't always fit the circumstances, because there was no "li" element children so why use the "ul" tag in the first place?

As soon as I posted this, I found the answer to the second issue. The Map Layers div was actually an image of the Map Layers icon that was in a custom widget and was easily fixable.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
